# DISTINCT is not working in sqlite query android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
 """select distinct "data" from (select * from "DemoName" inner join "patient" on "DemoName"."rowid" = "patient"."rowid" where "patient"."name" LIKE '%$pattern%' and length('$pattern') <= length("patient"."name") and "patient"."archived" = 'false'
                 union
                select * from "DemoName" inner join "patient" on "DemoName"."rowid" = "patient"."rowid" where "DemoName"."word" match '$pattern*' and "patient"."archived" = 'false' and score < 800 and top = 30
                ) ORDER BY CASE  WHEN name LIKE '$pattern%' THEN 0 WHEN name LIKE '%$pattern%' THEN 1 ELSE score END LIMIT 80""".trimIndent()
```

This is the query I am using for search distinct. But I am getting duplicate values in this query because of union operator